# Change only one specific color with css

Tags: css, colors

I have a little picture and i want to change in some cases only the color black to white using css. Is this possible?
(the picture is a .gif and the Browserversion is old - Firefox version 39 - a newer one is not allowed)

invert() changes too much

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How black is the black compared to other colors? Would it be obvious if for example you drew the image on a canvas then plodded through looking for areas which had very little light in them? I imagine pure black is unlikely.

Comment: @A Haworth Thanks a lot for your answer. It is very black compared to other colors. I think this could be a possible solution. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know this is **NOT** possible, you can try every filter there is: [CSS Filters](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp) to see if any (or the combination of many) gives you the desired effect.

I recommend you to change the approach and use **SVG** instead (with svg you can pretty much do whatever you need, check [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)), if you need an animation you could also try with Lottie, which helps you insert an After Effect animation into your code.

Check the oficial website for more info: [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the hint for svg. In a further step i will try to change our approch to SVG.
For the moment we solved the problem by adding the "inverted" picture at the bottom of the original. now i can only change the position in css (this works well because we only use very small pictures).